# Angular directive parent scope

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I'm building a directive that decorates a table header item and sort the data upon the click event. I cannot apply the changes on the data model to the parent scope using the directive scope.

vm.data is an array on the parent scope that contains the data I want to sort in the directive.
After the click the data object in the directive has changed but the parent is still in the same order.

I dont want to access the parent scope using $parent, What I'm missing ??

```
<th sortable="browser" data="vm.data">Browser</th>
```

directive code:

```
angular
    .module("app")
    .directive("sortable", ['lodash', sortableDirective]);

function sortableDirective(lodash) {
    return {
        restrict: "A",
        scope:{
            data:"="
        },
        controller:function($scope){

        },
        link: function (scope, element, attributes) {

            var sorted = undefined;
            var col = attributes['sortable'];
            var oldClass = 'sorting'

            attributes.$$element.addClass(oldClass);
            $(element).on("click", sort);

            function changeClass(){
                if(sorted=='asc'){
                    attributes.$$element.removeClass(oldClass);
                    attributes.$$element.addClass('sorting_asc');
                    oldClass = 'sorting_asc';
                }
                else if(sorted=='desc'){
                    attributes.$$element.removeClass(oldClass);
                    attributes.$$element.addClass('sorting_desc');
                    oldClass='sorting_desc';
                }

            }

            function sort() {

                if (sorted == 'asc') {
                    sorted = 'desc';
                }
                else {
                    sorted = 'asc';
                }

                scope.data = lodash.sortBy(scope.data, function (o) {
                    return o[col];
                });

                if (sorted == 'desc') {
                    lodash.reverse(scope.data);
                }

                changeClass();
            }
        }
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are using jQuery to listen to change on the element. So just change this line:

```
$(element).on("click", sort);
```

to

```
element.on("click", sort);
```

The 2nd attribute i.e. `element` is already an instance of jQlite if jQuery is not available and will be an instance of jQuery if jQuery is available.

In any case, there is a method available [`.on`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element) which will be executed on the value change. Since you again wrapped it to `$()`, the Angular was not getting notified of the change in the data.

#### Edit:

On the 2nd walk through of your code, I see the actual problem. You are reassigning the complete `scope.data` in the `sort()` method which is breaking the pass by reference behavior of Javascript (or in any OOPS programming).

The pass by reference will only work if you continue to modify your **SAME** reference variable. Noticed the word, **SAME**?? By writing `scope.data = lodash.sortBy(scope.data, function (o) {})` you removed the reference of the actual data passed to the directive. Hence the values are not updated.

So to fix this problem, you have a few options:

1. Change your sorting code to not reassign the complete `scope.data` variable **RECOMMENDED** (use inbuilt [`sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) method)
2. Pass the modified `data` to the parent scope using `scope.$emit()`
3. Or use the `$parent` property which you don't want to use

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I've seen the stupid mistake of replacing the reference and implemented the 1 solution using the built-in sort method, but the changes were not propagated, even If I attached the sort to the element and not the $(element).  I've added the scope.$apply() as suggested by georgeawg and the changes were "going up".

Answer (score 0):

The bidirectional binding **will** update the parent on each digest cycle but the click handler needs to invoke that digest cycle with `$apply`:

```
    link: function (scope, element, attributes) {

        var sorted = undefined;
        var col = attributes['sortable'];
        var oldClass = 'sorting'

        element.addClass(oldClass);

        //REPLACE this
        //$(element).on("click", sort);
        //
        //WITH this           
        element.on("click", function (e) {
            sort();
            scope.$apply();
        });

        function changeClass(){
            if(sorted=='asc'){
                element.removeClass(oldClass);
                element.addClass('sorting_asc');
                oldClass = 'sorting_asc';
            }
            else if(sorted=='desc'){
                element.removeClass(oldClass);
                element.addClass('sorting_desc');
                oldClass='sorting_desc';
            }

        }
```

The `ng-click` directive automatically invokes `$apply` but when the click event is handled by [AngularJS jqLite](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element#angular-s-jqlite), the code needs to notify the AngularJS framework.

From the Docs:

> ### `$apply([exp]);`
>
> `$apply()` is used to execute an expression in angular from outside of the angular framework. (For example from browser DOM events, setTimeout, XHR or third party libraries). Because we are calling into the angular framework we need to perform proper scope life cycle of [exception handling](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$exceptionHandler), [executing watches](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$digest).

-- [AngularJS $rootScope.scope API Reference -- $apply](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$apply)

Comment: Thanks the scope.$apply() was crucial to the final solution.